# Installing Linux on HP T620 Thin Client

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader

I got hold of some HP T620 Thin Clients and I planned to install something like Ubuntu, raspbian or Lubuntu on it, as this seems to work according to some forums.

The client has 8 GB RAM, 16GB M.2 SSD. I prepared all the USB sticks for installation with Rufus and tried chosing MBR as well as GPT. Ubuntu & Lubuntu are the most recent versions.

Unfortunately, I stumbled accross mainly two problems:

1. With Lubuntu, I can start the installation process, but it always fails at installing grub. Errors are "Grub dummy installation failed" or something like "cannot install grub".
   I tried to skip this step in the installation and tried two things:

- Later running a rescue / repair programm, was not successful
- Tried to boot the installation without grub, did not work. According
  to some articles, grub is not even necessary anymore. Shouldnt it be possible to put the bootloader on USB and from there boot the OS on the disk?

2. With Ubuntu, I come to the grub menu, and no matter if I select "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu (safe graphics)", I just get a blank screen. Nothing more happens.

anybody has any ideas on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, added that I used the most recent versions. Yes, I also tried with Lubuntu, as I wrote. Although Ubuntu should run as well, since these Thin Clients were even capable of running Windows 7, afaik.

Comment: These are capable for Win7 Std Embedded, not sure if regular Win7 would work. I can't find whether these have UEFI or legacy BIOS. Could you maybe add photos of the BIOS and the installation error message?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My sollution during install was, de-select the LVM group option when you select the drive to install ubuntu on.

no errors during install.

I just installed Ubuntu server 20.04.3 LTS on my T620.
I've prepared my USB stick with the Raspbian imager tool, with custom iso of ubuntu server.